# Live Charts wpf Multiple axis + dateTime on X(below)

Tags: wpf, datetime, livecharts

Hey so I'm looking for a way to display a range of dates correctly on an Lvc chart.

Here's my code so far :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CleanSeparator" TargetType="lvc:Separator">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Row="2">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis Foreground="DodgerBlue" Title="Testing"/>
            <lvc:Axis Foreground="IndianRed" Title="Market" Position="RightTop">
                <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                    <lvc:Separator Style="{StaticResource CleanSeparator}"></lvc:Separator>
                </lvc:Axis.Separator>
            </lvc:Axis>

        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis LabelFormatter="{Binding XFormatter}" >

            </lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>    
        <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:LineSeries Values="200,210,260,71,55,120"  ScalesYAt="0"/>
            <!--Scales at blue axis, Axis[0]-->
            <lvc:LineSeries Values="20,30,40,20,10,100"  ScalesYAt="1"/>
            <!--Scales at red axis, Axis[1]-->
            <!--Scales at green axis, Axis[2]-->
        </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
</Grid>
```

And the idea is to have the AxisX display a range of dates let's say 2017.01.22 -> 2018.01.22 ,
Any clues /hints would be greatly appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question? You want formatter? `XFormatter = val => new DateTime(val).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");`

Comment: I am not sure how to combine the values + a series of DateTime (dates) 

What I need is basically a chart with 2 lines (Y) and a X that's the span of some dates . Is there a possible way to hardcode it? I managed combining with a Series but only 1 Y Axis .

Comment: You can hard code the labels with `<lvc:Axis Title="Month" Labels="John, Susan, Charles" />` (see mapped labels at https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Labels).